# Can't synchronize call to notify()

Tags: android, multithreading

Forgive me, but i am not able to get a call on NotificationBuilder's notify() method. I have this code:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(
              new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    synchronized (this) {
            Builder notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(c);
        notif.setContentIntent(contIntent)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setTicker("Notification ticker")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Vinceri")
                .setContentText("Ha recibido una oferta de trabajo")
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        notif.notify();
        }
}
}
```

And no matter where i put the synchronized block, i get the same exception:

```
04-05 10:42:55.116: E/AndroidRuntime(18244): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
04-05 10:42:55.116: E/AndroidRuntime(18244): java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before notifyAll()
04-05 10:42:55.116: E/AndroidRuntime(18244):    at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
04-05 10:42:55.116: E/AndroidRuntime(18244):    at com.publidirecta.vinceriazafata.NotificationService$1.run(NotificationService.java:126)
04-05 10:42:55.116: E/AndroidRuntime(18244):    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

It is maybe a noob question but... what I must to do to not receive that Exception? thank you.

Comment: what are you trying to do in this code?...

Comment: You need to lock the `notif` object. But you synchronize on `this`.

Comment: Silly question. Thank you! if you put it in an answer I will upvote you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to add notification to the android notification drawer.. You need to do following:

```
Builder notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(c);
        notif.setContentIntent(contIntent)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setTicker("Notification ticker")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Vinceri")
                .setContentText("Ha recibido una oferta de trabajo")
                .setAutoCancel(true);
      //create notification from builder
      Notification notification = notif.build();
      //get instance of NotificationManager
      NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      //call notify method of NotificationManager to add this notification to android notification drawer..
      notificationmanager.notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: That is more than I asked. Thank you very much Praful.