# Notifications in Android - App stops after notify()

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, notifications

I have a simple android app to display a notification on screen. The app runs properly till builder.setContentIntent() and displays the Toast message properly. If the line, manager.notify() is not commented the App stops. I am using Android Studio.

MainActivity.java

here is my code for notifications

```
private void addNotification() {
        message = txtMessage.getText().toString();
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setContentTitle("You have a new message").setContentText(message);
        // Add as notification
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

       PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "contentIntentset",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //manager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

}

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NotificationView"
            android:label="Details of notification"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Can someone help?

Comment: what error u r getting,pls post the error trace,without manager.notify() notification will not show

Comment: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before notify()

Comment: from where u are calling the addNotification() function.The notify() method has to be called from within a synchronized context, ie from inside a synchronized block.

Comment: b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addNotification();
            }
        });

Comment: From the onCreate() function

Comment: How do I call it from a synchronized block?

Comment: if u are calling from onclik of a button, then no problem with that, r u using any thread inside that onclick function

Comment: Can you tell me what the problem could be?

Comment: No there isn't any thread inside onclick. It is just the addNotification() call.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829520/cant-synchronize-call-to-notify, exactly the same issue

Comment: Still get the same error

Comment: I forgot .setSmallIcon(). I added that and it worked!!